# How to make Windows Phone Listbox unscrollable?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, listbox

I have a Listbox in my Windows Phone application. Now, the listbox is scrollable (by default), so if I touch the listbox with my finger, it scrolls. I want to make it unscrollable (i.e. when I touch and drag listbox, nothing happens). How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar Question at [WP7 Prevent ListBox scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679326/wp7-prevent-listbox-scrolling)
Where the listbox scrolling independent of the page is locked, but still allows the page to scroll (if necessary)

There should be a "scrollable" or similar property of the listBox control that you can set to false to prevent the listBox from scrolling.

Comment: Thank you! Haven't noticed that question when I was searching.