# Display multiple items dynamically using DataTemplate but not using listbox or similar

Tags: silverlight, xaml, data-binding, mvvm, windows-phone-8

I'm using MVVM and I've got an object similar to the structure defined below. Everything is dynamic, so the number of rows will vary, the number of groups could vary and the number of labels and values displayed within each group varies as well.

- Row1

  - Group1

    - Label1 : Value1
    - Label2 : Value2
    - Label3 : Value3
    - Label4 : Value4
  - Group2

    - Label1 : Value1
    - Label2 : Value2
    - Label3 : Value3
    - Label4 : Value4
  - Group3

    - Label1 : Value1
    - Label2 : Value2
    - Label3 : Value3
    - Label4 : Value4
- Row2

  - Group1

    - Label1 : Value1
    - Label2 : Value2
    - Label3 : Value3
    - Label4 : Value4
  - Group2

    - Label1 : Value1
    - Label2 : Value2
    - Label3 : Value3
    - Label4 : Value4
  - Group3

    - Label1 : Value1
    - Label2 : Value2
    - Label3 : Value3
    - Label4 : Value4

It is all defined in a database and while my object (made up of numerous viewmodel using observable collections) is defined correctly and I can display all the data accordingly, I don't like what I did!!

I have a LongListMultiSelector that holds all my rows (that part is fine) but then I've got a ListBox for each of the groups and within each of the groups I've got another ListBox to display all my labels and values BUT

My problem is that I can "drag" the groups (though hard) but I can drag the labels and values as they are items in lists which looks awful!

Is there a way to display this data in a grid like without having the scrolling?? I just want to display the data as mentioned above, but I don't want the user to be able to drag anything, except scroll from row to row if that makes sense!

Is there a way to disable the scrolling of a listbox maybe? Should it be done like this? Also I don't want to use to be able to select/highlight a specific label or field by tapping on it, so this parts need to be disabled as well or at least the highlight needs to be the same color as the default in order not to show it!

Oh, one last thing, if I leave the listbox (and disable scrolling or highlighting) or I use another control to achieve the same, is there a way that a user can drag these items as if they had the fingers on an item on the LongListMultiSelector?

I'm not sure to be honest. Can anyone advice?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found an [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679326/wp7-prevent-listbox-scrolling) on stackoverflow, which is what I needed to resolved my problem.

I'm not sure whether this is correct or not, but this is definitely did the trick for me.

I now need to figure out how to disable the "tapping" when flicking through my LongListMultiSelector, but that's another problem, but overall, having listbox, within listbox within a LongMultiSelector can be handled very nicely by disabling the scrolling.